# Trying to obtain Azimuth (Yaw) from recorded Android Sensor.TYPE_ROTATION_VECTOR data?

Tags: android, android-sensors

I have been given an Excel file of Sensor.TYPE_ROTATION_VECTOR data logged on an Android 5.1 Phone. This is to support some research.

It comprises of the rotation data in the form of the Unit Quaternion representing the rotation. I've been told the columns are: -

Timestamp, [x*sin(θ/2)], [y*sin(θ/2)], [z*sin(θ/2)], [cos(θ/2)]

some example data would be:

0.437745917,0.013828,0.029528,0.924988,0.378594

The Unit Quaternion in elements 2..5 is basically what is returned by the sensor.

I need to obtain the Azimuth (Yaw) with respect to Magnetic North for each row. My understanding from hunting around on the Web that this is essentially the rotation around the Z axis. I've tried various combinations to extract the Azimuth and seem to get crazy values back. Just need the correct formula, any help would be gratefully received.

Many thanks,

Shaun

Comment: Azimuth != Yaw. Azimuth is the absolute heading, Yaw is the difference between the previous heading and the current heading (how much the device rotated around the Z-axis). Have a look here: https://developer.android.com/reference/android/hardware/SensorManager.html#getOrientation(float[], float[])